# How to update tabbar badge-icon in Xamarin.Forms.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I can successfully work with the badge on my tabbar if i use it straight in my ViewWillAppear function but if i create a function where i try to control it then the badge does not appear.

This is the tabbedpaged renderer where I have to the function that changes the badge.

```
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        if (TabBar == null) return;
        if (TabBar.Items == null) return;

        var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
        if (tabs != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
            {
                UpdateItem(TabBar.Items[i], tabs.Children[i].Icon);
            }
        }

        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }

    private void UpdateItem(UITabBarItem item, string icon)
    {
        TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.White;
    }

    public void UpdateBadge ()
    {
        var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
        if (tabs != null)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var tab = TabBar.Items[3];
                tab.BadgeValue = "New";
                tab.BadgeColor = UIColor.Red;
            });

        }
    }
```

Then I have another file where I handle a pushnotification and this is where I call the `UpdateBadge`function to both push a notification and also update the badge in the app.

```
    void IPush.SendPush()
    {
        var notification = new UILocalNotification();
        notification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.PresentLocalNotificationNow(notification);

        TabbedPage_Renderer tpr = new TabbedPage_Renderer();
        tpr.UpdateBadge();
    }
```

But as stated above this does not add the badge.

If I however add...

```
var tab = TabBar.Items[3];
tab.BadgeValue = "New";
tab.BadgeColor = UIColor.Red;
```

...inside the `ViewWillAppear` straight away it successfully shows an iconbadge when i start the app up but the idea is to control it so i can update the badge whenever i want.

Answer (score 0):

We should not use the instance of the Renderer directly.

If you want to change the UI in the platform's renderer, we can try to define a [BindableProperty](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/) in the forms. Then tell the renderer do some configuration when this property changed.

Firstly, define a BindableProperty in the page which you want to change its Badge like:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BadgeTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BadgeText), typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), "0");
public string BadgeText {
    set
    {
        SetValue(BadgeTextProperty, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(BadgeTextProperty);
    }
}
```

Secondly, in the renderer, we can set the badge text when this property changed like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
{
    UpdateItem(TabBar.Items[i], tabs.Children[i].Icon);
    //register the property changed event
    tabs.Children[i].PropertyChanged += TabbarPageRenderer_PropertyChanged;
}
private void TabbarPageRenderer_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var page = sender as Page;
    if (page == null)
        return;

    if (e.PropertyName == "BadgeText")
    {
        if (CheckValidTabIndex(page, out int tabIndex))
        {
            switch(tabIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    UpdateBadge(TabBar.Items[tabIndex], (page as MainPage).BadgeText);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //Second Page, you can expand this switch depending on your tabs children

                    UpdateBadge(TabBar.Items[tabIndex], (page as SecondPage).BadgeText);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }   
        return;
    }
}
public bool CheckValidTabIndex(Page page, out int tabIndex)
{
    tabIndex = Tabbed.Children.IndexOf(page);
    return tabIndex < TabBar.Items.Length;
}
private void UpdateItem(UITabBarItem item, string icon)
{
    TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.White;
    ...//set the tabItem
}
private void UpdateBadge(UITabBarItem item, string badgeText)
{
    item.BadgeValue = text;
    item.BadgeColor = UIColor.Red;
}
```

At last, set the BadgeText in the forms when you want to update the badge.

Comment: if i use this code straight up then all the tabs get a badge with the icon.png name of each emote

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez I separate the update method, and you can use my new code to detect which tab's badge will change. Please check my update.

Comment: Cant get TabbarPageRenderer_PropertyChanged to trigger when badgeproperty is set

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Set the value of BindableProperty in the forms(e.g. BadgeText I defined above) to fire the property changed event.

Comment: I do set BadgeText = "test"; right when u enter a certain page. It does not fire the event

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Only the property changed will fire this event, I find a sample project for you to refer to: [https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge)

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez I make a simple sample for you referring to: [https://github.com/lt0526/TabbedPageDemo](https://github.com/lt0526/TabbedPageDemo)

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Hi CarlosRodrigez, can this sample help you?

Comment: I dont know why i cant get it to work :( I ahve 4 different tabs. I want the 4th tab to show an icon on and off and i want to be able to control it from the app.xaml.cs

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Click my button on the page will change the badge. I create a `BindableProperty`, when it changes the property changed event(in the renderer) will fire. If you want the 4th tab's badge to change in the app.xaml, you can modify this `BindableProperty` in app.xaml.

Comment: Hi will try this in a few hours again!